# symfony form choice with entity get result

Tags: forms, symfony, entity

I'm trying to get the result of my choice form.

The form is like this :

```
$users = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->findAll();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($users)
    ->add('users', 'entity', array(
        'label' => 'Pick that user',
        'class' => 'UserBundle:User',
        'choice_label' => 'usFirstname'))
        ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Submit'));
```

Then I want to get the user picked, I try several things, but nothing worked...
It should be something like this :

```
$user_picked = 
$em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->
findBy(array('usFirstname' => $form->getForm()->get('users')->getData()));
```

How should I do to get the user picked after the button 'Submit' is clicked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic of the form builder does this work for you.
If you dump the data `dump($form->get('users')->getData())` it will be an instance of the user for the choice in the form.  No need to to do an extra query.

Also the choice_label just filters what is in the text of the select option, not the value.

Example;

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\User,
    AppBundle\Form\MyFormType;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route,
    Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter,
    Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request,
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class MyController extends Controller 
{
    public function addAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new MyFormType(), null, []);
        $form->add('submit', 'submit', [
                'label' => 'Create',
                'attr'  => ['class' => 'btn btn-success pull-right']
            ]
        );
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            dump($form->get('users')->getData());
            exit(0);
        }

        return $this->render('AppBundle:user:form.html.twig', [
                'form' => $form->createView()
            ]
        );
    }
}

<?php 
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType,
    Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface,
    Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver,
    Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

    class MyFormType extends AbstractType
    {

        /**
         * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
         * @param array $options
         */
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder->add('users', 'entity', [
                'required' => false,
                'class' => 'AppBundle:User',
                'choice_label' => 'usFirstname',
                'expanded' => false,
                'multiple' => false,
            ]);
        }

        /**
         * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
         */
        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => null,
            ));
        }

        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getName()
        {
            return 'my_form';
        }

    }
```

Comment: I think that's the good way to do ! Thanks !
But "var_dump($form->get('users')->getData());" is always returning null... I don't know why.

Comment: btw, There is a `dump()` function in Symfony to show data, it will be visible in the debug profiler.  Can you show you controller code for the function that processes the form?

Comment: Oh thank you for the tip, I'm beginner...
After the form I just try to display the result like this : 

        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            dump($form->get('users')->getData());
        }

Comment: @user3822337 I have added a basic code example. Note; this form is not tied to an entity or registered as a service, just a basic example to get you going

Comment: My bad, I forgot the "$form->handleRequest($request);"
Thanks a lot !